# Application crashes on Activity.getSystemService - Android - 5.1.1

Tags: android, android-service

While getting the instance of system service using context.getSystemService, my application crashes randomly. This crash is observed only on android 5.1.1 and M.

I am using below code to get the instance of location manager, but it crashes.

```
 LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

**Below is the stack trace for the same:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parcel has been finalized!
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:511)
    at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.getService(ServiceManagerNative.java:123)
    at android.os.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:55)
    at android.app.ContextImpl$27.createService(ContextImpl.java:538)
    at android.app.ContextImpl$ServiceFetcher.getService(ContextImpl.java:341)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.getSystemService(ContextImpl.java:2079)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getSystemService(ContextThemeWrapper.java:113)
    at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:5233)
```

Comment: which service are you trying to instantiate?

Comment: Can you expand the question by showing the code?

Comment: Whether you defined permissions in manifest file?

Comment: yes, its is working below 5.1.1 and on 5.1.1 its crashing randomly not always

Answer (score 0):

Update your SDK, I am sure your problem will be fix.
Because I was facing the same problem with updated android version from 5.0 to 5.1.1 and my apps goes crashed when I attempt login.